# How to get Exim4 to send from a mail. subdomain?

Tags: email, subdomain, exim

Currently Exim4 is sending from example.com, but as I understand it is better (for spam ratings?) to send from a subdomain like mail.example.com.  How do I make it so that the headers of my emails show it coming from mail.example.com?

Sorry, it must be a very simple answer, but I can't figure it out and searching doesn't seem to bring anything (another sign it is a simple answer).

Comment: I have no knowledge of it being better to send from a mail subdomain. It is better to send from a machine that is validated by a SPF record.

Comment: Thanks, I read it here: http://www.systemajik.com/blog/detecting-email-server-forgery/ "A legitimate email server has ... a static addresss with a DNS PTR record specifying the host’s FQDN (Fully Qualified Domain Name).  This should have at least three domain components: hostname, sub-domain, and the TLD (top level domain).  For example mail.example.com instead of example.com."

Answer (score 1):

Now that I understand what your asking.

Your (or your ISP's, depending upon your situation) DNS should have these entries for your outbound MTA:
`mail.yourdomain.tld IN A 192.0.2.19`
`19.2.0.192.in-addr.arpa IN PTR mail.yourdomain.tld`

This has nothing to do with the domain the email is coming from.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that... do I need the A entry if I already have a wildcard subdomain entry set (`*.example.tld`)?

Comment: And I don't understand how this affects outgoing email... do I need to have a separate IP for my mail server then?  Sorry for being dense.